# Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.internalRabbitListenerEndpointRegistry'

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have a simple spring-boot application with a rabbit sender and a receiver. I want to write some receiver tests where I am running a **rabbitmq docker** instance as Junit Class Rule ([RabbitContainerRule](https://geowarin.github.io/docker-junit-rule.html))and then sending a message using rabbitTemplate and the test verifies if the receiver receives the same message. But I am getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.internalRabbitListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIllegalStateException: Fatal exception on listener startup
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178)

Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.QueuesNotAvailableException: Cannot prepare queue for listener. Either the queue doesn't exist or the broker will not allow us to use it.
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:599)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1424)

Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'my-message-queue' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66)
```

*If I create the queue manually(by stopping at a breakpoint) in the docker instance using admin console,  my test passes.*

Also, if I test it manually using the docker rabbit instance, my spring boot application creates queue successfully. So what is causing it to not create in the test?

I am using **spring-amqp 1.7.4 RELEASE**

Receiver code:

```
@RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(
        value = @Queue(value = "my-message-queue", durable = "true",
                arguments = {
                        @Argument(name = "x-dead-letter-exchange", value = "my-message-exchange-dead-letter"),
                        @Argument(name = "x-dead-letter-routing-key", value = "my-message-queue")}),
        exchange = @Exchange(value = "my-message-exchange", type = "topic", durable = "true"),
        key = "my-message-rk")
)
public void handleMessage(MyMessage message) {
    MESSAGE_LOG.info("Receiving message: " + message);
}
```

Also I am not creating any @Bean for *my-message-queue* in Configurations and rely on **@RabbitListener** to create one for me. But I am creating ConnectionFactory, RabbitTemplate and SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory beans in my config.

Comment: Do you have `RabbitAdmin` bean?

Comment: How about just share with us the whole application somewhere in GitHub?

Comment: Thanks Artem. Adding the RabbitAdmin bean in the test config solved this problem. Also, @EnableRabbit was missing on my configuration file.

Comment: All this while I was thinking how did it work when running this spring boot app, until I found out that the spring boot application creates it (RabbitAdmin) magically using this property "spring.rabbitmq.dynamic=true". Thank you once again.

Comment: Done. Thank you. Really appreciate your help @ArtemBilan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@EnableRabbit` is necessary on some `@Configuration` class to let your application context to parse `@RabbitListener`.

To let the application to create queues and exchanges and bindings between them automatically, and the `RabbitAdmin` bean must be present in the configuration.

See Reference Manual for more information: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/

Answer (score 0):

The class where you are building your queues should be annotated with @Configuration annotation, otherwise, spring will not be able to create the queues at the time of start up